# If $\gamma :[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is smooth then $\gamma(t)=x$ has finite number of solutions

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

Let $\gamma :[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ be a smooth curve ($\gamma$ is differentiable with $\gamma'(t)\neq \mathbf{0}$ for all $t\in[a,b]$). Show that, for $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$, the equation $\gamma(t)=x$ has at most finite number of solutions.

Comment: You should probably share some work, thoughts, or context for this problem. Otherwise it seems to be a homework dump

Comment: Using the hints below I found the solution. Should I edit the question to include it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If for an infinite set of $\{t_i\}$ we had that $\gamma (t_i)=x,$ then by compactness of $[a,b]$ (see that this is a necessary condition) there would be an accumulation point $t^* \in [a,b]$.

By continuity of $\gamma $, $$\gamma (t^*)=x.$$

At $t^*$, 
$$ \gamma ' (t^*)=\lim _{t_i \rightarrow t^*} \frac {\gamma (t_i)-\gamma (t^*)}{t_i-t^*}=\lim _{t_i \rightarrow t^*}\frac {x-x}{t_i-t^*}=0.$$

A contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose there are infinitely many $t$ such that $\gamma(t)=x$. Since $[a,b]$ is compact there is actually a sequence $t_n$ that converges to some $t_0$ such that $\gamma(t_n)=x$. In particular $\gamma(t_0)=x$. Show this implies that $\gamma'(t_0)=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: As a first step, show that for each $t_0\in [a,b]$ there is a neighborhood $U$ of $t_0$ such that $\gamma (t) \ne \gamma (t_0)$ for $t\in U\setminus \{t_0\}.$